# unable to iterate over rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this question has been asked many times but I have tried almost all methods I am trying to iterate over rows in DataFrame using following code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"file.csv")

for row in df:
    print(row)
```

there is only one column in csv file and it only prints `header` of file. I have also used `.items()` , `.iterrows()` and `.itertuples()`, all these methods give tuples as output which I don't need. Further task I am trying to do in loop only accepts output from `for row in df:`. kindly help that how can I print actual rows this way rather than just header name. Thank you.

Comment: You can iterate as `for row in df[col_name].to_list():`

Comment: Use `for _, row in df.iterrows()`

Comment: @Ajay This is the answer can you please post in answer section so I can mark it. Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using the specific column on which you want to iterate

```
for row in df[col_name].to_list():
```

Answer (score 2):

The df.iterrows() method iterates over each row of a dataframe, returning a tuple of (row_number, row_data). So to just get the row data, you can unpack each tuple as part of the iterration and only use the second part:

```
for num, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```